# SQL - how to select order by increase count loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select data using SQL order by increase count loop.

This is hard to explain without example.

There is a table data below:

SELECT * FROM data_table ORDER BY `point` desc

```
-------------------
| point | data | cat |
===================
| 9 | a | 5 |
| 8 | b | 5 |
| 7 | c | 4 |
| 6 | d | 1 |
| 5 | e | 2 |
| 4 | f | 1 |
| 3 | g | 3 |
| 2 | h | 2 |
| 1 | i | 3 |
```

SELECT ~~ ORDER BY increase 'cat' loop.

expect result:

```
-------------------
| point | data | cat |
===================
| 6 | d | 1 | -> There are two '1', but this one have bigger point value.(6>4)
| 5 | e | 2 | -> There are two '2', but this one have bigger point value.(5>2)
| 3 | g | 3 |
| 7 | c | 4 |
| 9 | a | 5 |
| 4 | f | 1 |
| 2 | h | 2 |
| 1 | i | 3 |
              -> Skip cat '4' because there are no '4' cat value more.
| 8 | b | 5 |
```

I'm using sql in php.

If there is no way to get this, I think I have to find or write php code.

Please give me a help to query this as easily as possible.

Thanks.

**In my case, `id` is not an actual "id", just a INT field. -> fix to "point"**

It means "can be duplicated and have big Integer value".

Comment: So what's the PHP solution you have? May be, someone or myself can translate into MySQL query.

Comment: Oh, I edit that sentence. That was could bring misunderstand. I could not found any solution for this.

Comment: Okay great. Can you tell me what's the logic behind? Getting which `1` first? Or... You understand right? There are two or more `1`s.

Comment: Can't be done (with SQL, unless a cursor is used.)

Comment: Getting first one what have bigger id index value. You right, I miss that. Thanks.

Comment: @jarlh, Then how to use a cursor to get?

Comment: But the are also 2 "5" with a bigger id the the biggest id of "1". can you explain more about how you want to order the data ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know php or MySQL stored procedures.

Comment: @zionbenyacov, That's because 9a5 have greater id than 8b5 (9>8).

Comment: @RobertMoon - do you know the max amount  of rows for each "cat"?

Comment: @zionbenyacov, Oh yes. There is another table to store cat information. But to avoid complexity, please assume that max amount is "5" in this question.

Comment: @RobertMoon - there is probably a SQL solution - but I'm checking it now if its possible

Comment: @zionbenyacov, Thanks I just feel like you. I already found over one hour, but I failed..

Comment: @RobertMoon - please checkout my code I posted here below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROW_NUMBER function does not exist in MYSQL. But this should give you the desired results. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8704a/1/0)

```
SELECT t.point, t.data, t.cat
FROM data_table t
ORDER BY 
  FIND_IN_SET(t.point, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(point ORDER BY point DESC, cat ASC)
    FROM data_table t1
    where t1.cat = t.cat)),
  cat
```

Just in case (SQL Server):

```
SELECT *
FROM data_table t
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.cat ORDER BY t.id DESC), t.cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude - I got it working with a table "aaa" same as yours
you will need to test it much more to verify the code

```
select *
from
(
    select main.* 

                ,@cur_value:=main.cat as cur_value
                ,@row_num := if (@cur_value = @prev_value, @row_num + 1, 0) as indexer
                ,@prev_value := @cur_value as prev_value
                ,if (@row_num > 0, @row_num * 1000 * main.cat, main.cat) as sort_index
    from 
    (
     select * from aaa order by cat asc , id desc
     ) main
    ,
    (SELECT @row_num :=0, @prev_value := 0, @cur_value := 0) inn
) sort
order by sort.sort_index
```

You will just need to remove rows as cat=4 with only I row

Also - you might need to change the value "1000" to something dynamic

Comment: I try to apply on my data, but doesn't work. (mixed up)
In my case, `id` is not actual "id". It's just a INT field.

Comment: I wrote the script according to your table example